# Ruby on Rails, generating xml (ruby 2 and rails 4.2.1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, passenger

We have a page that should deliver XML. This page is kind of slow since it have to generate a lot of XML. 
We have newly upgraded ruby from 1.9.3 to 2.2.2 and rails 3.2.17 to 4.2.1
Our server is using nginx and passenger to receive requests

When we are access our server and get the XML we get the respond
notis that all other pages is working

```
<hash>
  <status>500</status>
  <error>Internal Server Error</error> 
</hash>
```

or

```
Incomplete response received from application
```

In Rails log:

```
BankTransaction Load (1.2ms) SELECT “bank_transactions”.* FROM  “bank_transactions” WHERE (is_split = false) AND “bank_transactions”.“id” = $1 LIMIT 1 [[“id”, 178091]]
Invoice Load (1.5ms) SELECT “invoices”.* FROM “invoices” WHERE “invoices”.“deleted_at” IS NULL AND “invoices”.“id” = $1 LIMIT 1 [[“id”, 149471]]
(125.8ms) SELECT COUNT FROM “reconciliation_lines” WHERE “reconciliation_lines”.“reconciliation_id” = $1 AND (id 251128 and parent_type=‘Invoice’) [[“reconciliation_id”, 157402]]
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 19815ms (ActiveRecord: 17628.6ms)

RuntimeError (unsupported: FalseClass):
lib/bank_transaction_xml/bt_to_xml.rb:43:in `block (4 levels) in to_xml’
lib/bank_transaction_xml/bt_to_xml.rb:31:in `block (3 levels) in to_xml’
lib/bank_transaction_xml/bt_to_xml.rb:29:in `block (2 levels) in to_xml’
lib/bank_transaction_xml/bt_to_xml.rb:6:in `block in to_xml’
lib/bank_transaction_xml/bt_to_xml.rb:5:in `new’
lib/bank_transaction_xml/bt_to_xml.rb:5:in `to_xml’
lib/bank_transaction_xml/bt_to_xml.rb:227:in `block (3 levels) in list_xml’
lib/bank_transaction_xml/bt_to_xml.rb:226:in `each’
lib/bank_transaction_xml/bt_to_xml.rb:226:in `block (2 levels) in list_xml’
lib/bank_transaction_xml/bt_to_xml.rb:222:in `block in list_xml’
lib/bank_transaction_xml/bt_to_xml.rb:221:in `new’
lib/bank_transaction_xml/bt_to_xml.rb:221:in `list_xml’
app/controllers/balance_report_controller.rb:91:in `block (2 levels) in index’
app/controllers/balance_report_controller.rb:88:in `index’
```

As you can see, it just stopps and exits.
Passenger is logging too, it have some more interesting log.

```
App 551 stderr: /fakturabank_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/lib/nokogiri/xml/document.rb:82: [BUG]
App 551 stderr: Segmentation fault at 0×00000000000040
App 551 stderr: ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295) [x86_64-linux]
…..

App 551 stderr:
App 551 stderr: [NOTE]
App 551 stderr: You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
App 551 stderr: Bug reports are welcome.
App 551 stderr: For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html
App 551 stderr:
[ 2015-06-18 09:45:33.5083 25387/7fcac95af700 age/Hel/Req/Utils.cpp:89 ]: [Client 2-1569] Sending 502 response: application did not send a complete response
[ 2015-06-18 09:45:36.0178 25387/7fcad02f2700 App/Poo/AnalyticsCollection.h:93 ]: Process (pid=1805, group=/fakturabank_path/current/public (staging)#default) no longer exists! Detaching it from the pool.
[ 2015-06-18 09:45:36.0180 25387/7fcad02f2700 age/Hel/Main.cpp:732 ]: Disconnecting long-running connections for process 1805, application /fakturabank_path/current/public (staging)#default
App 24184 stdout:
```

When we are doing this in development environment it all works good, it still take time.
If we use less data it work on server and on development. And it nota specific point it breaks.

eksempel
  5 bank transaction always work
 50 bank transaction work from time to time like 5 out of 10
100 bank transaction never work

I have tried to downgrade ruby version to 2.1.0, no luck there. Alse I tried to downgrade ruby version to 2.0.0, it work alot better but still not all the time.

Why??
I thing it is something with passenger and ruby 2.1 and 2.2?
Any idea?? what i can to to keep using ruby 2.2.2

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says, you may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries (that is, not in Passenger). Try reporting a bug to the Ruby authors. But I think the culprit is most likely in one of the native extensions you're using. I have no idea which native extensions you are using in your app, so the best thing you can do is to inspect them one-by-one, make educated guesses about which one may be crashing Ruby, then contact its author.

Comment: So I should try to remove my gems one-by-one, and see if it works?

Comment: That would be a sound strategy.